# Saving scipy griddata as singleband raster

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, gdal

I have a csv file containing `lon;lat;depth`-points. I want to interpolate these to a regular grid and save the outcome as a singleband (geo)raster. I can already interpolate and show the outcomes in matplotlib (but thats not really needed).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy.ma as ma
from numpy.random import uniform, seed

points = np.loadtxt('npcsv.csv',delimiter=";")
xi = np.linspace(589000,603500,1000)
yi = np.linspace(6965000,6980000,1000)

zi = griddata((points[:,0], points[:,1]), points[:,2], (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='cubic')

CS = plt.contour(xi,yi,zi,1,linewidths=0.5,colors='k')
CS = plt.contourf(xi,yi,zi,2,cmap=plt.cm.jet)
plt.colorbar() # draw colorbar

plt.scatter(points[:,0],points[:,1],marker='o',c='b',s=5)
plt.xlim(589000,603500)
plt.ylim(6965000,6980000)
plt.title('mydiagram')
plt.show()
```

Is there a way I can directly write the `griddata` or `zi` to a e.g. .tiff file? When I `print` the `zi` it just gives me a numpy-array of `NaN,NaN,.....`. I have the simplified files on gist: https://gist.github.com/willemvanopstal/a92b1b302870855c5fecb3c4e0b54b85

Comment: Any reason why `plt.savefig()` does not work for you?

Comment: @VBB I don't want to save the plot. I'm only interested in the interpolated raster (at the resolution I specified)

Comment: That's because the boundary values are nans! If you try `plt.imshow(zi)` you will see the image. You have the pixel values already. You can `np.savetxt` them, for instance. You can replace the nans with zeros if you prefer: `zi[np.isnan(zi)] = 0`

Comment: Thanks, that indeed works. Now I could save it as ascii raster. Still looking for maybe a more elegant solution: directly writing a geotiff or some sort.